# anchor build failed the error is use of unstable library feature 'build_hasher_simple_hash_one'

Tags: anchor

anchor build failed  the error is use of unstable library feature 'build_hasher_simple_hash_one'.

my rustc version is rustc 1.76.0-nightly  and added #![feature(build_hasher_simple_hash_one)] in the crate ,but it not work

Comment: Running into the same issue trying to build the Anchor CPI example from the Anchor Book. My observations: 1. The error is stating the feature is unstable in 1.76.0-nightly, which is false -> https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/111934 2. `Anchor build` seems to use the Solana toolchain? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71598808/why-is-anchor-build-and-cargo-build-bpf-showing-wrong-rustc-version

Comment: i have find a issue in -> https:github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/2528. maybe i have to follow it.   thanks you

Comment: This helped solve the issue for my case. https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/2755#issuecomment-1872994213